# Dropdown menu get object JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sapui5

I want get object name from dropdown menu when item is selected. how to get object from event itemSelect? Thanks for attention.

[Dropdown menu pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blFTq.png)

XML code:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
        <u:Menu items="{kepesertaanmodel>/}" id="menuEventingKepesertaan"
            itemSelect="handleMenuItemPressKepesertaan">
            <u:MenuItem
                text="{kepesertaanmodel>name}"
                icon="{kepesertaanmodel>icon}">

                <u:Menu items="{kepesertaanmodel>sub/}" id="submenuEventingKepesertaan"
                        itemSelect="handleSubMenuItemPressKepesertaan">
                    <u:MenuItem
                        text="{kepesertaanmodel>name}"
                        icon="{kepesertaanmodel>icon}"/>
                </u:Menu>
            </u:MenuItem>
        </u:Menu>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Javascript code:

```
handleMenuItemPressKepesertaan: function(oEvent) {          
    alert(oEvent.getSource().getItems().getBindingContext().getObject().name);
}
```

JSON structure:

```
        dropdownMenu: {
            kepesertaan:[
                {
                    name: "Menu1",
                    icon: "sap-icon://crop",
                    sub: [
                        { 
                            name: "Submenu1-1",
                            icon: "sap-icon://create-session"   
                        },
                        { 
                            name: "Submenu1-2",
                            icon: "sap-icon://create-form" 
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Menu2",
                    icon: "sap-icon://detail-view",
                    sub: [
                        { 
                            name: "Submenu2-1",
                            icon: "sap-icon://add-activity" 
                        },
                        { 
                            name: "Submenu2-2",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action" 
                        }
                    ]
                }           
            ]
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you ever check the documentation? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
oEvent.getParameter("item").getBinding("text").getValue("name")
```

You can also have a look at [this snippet](https://jsbin.com/yazenopipa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: i just can get text when i press the item, I want to get object in JSON when I press, etc: icon or other..

Comment: Which object? The whole object?